# Should I force developers to write ID of elements to write proper automated tests?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I am writing now selenium tests for React based webapp and facing some concerns about writing tests in selenium.

It looks like most of elements have no unique ID where I can simply find them using Selenium methods. I have used Selenium IDE and manually create tests and exported them to python but they typically look like this:

```
    browser.find_element(
        By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".MuiButton-containedPrimary > .MuiButton-label"
    ).click()
```

Which is in my opinion too complex for others to read and maintenance. Even if I write tests by myself they will be too hard to read. (even if they are fast developed)

My question is : **What is the best approach to acheive maintability and simplicity of tests?** **Should I force developers to give unique ids to core elements like buttons etc. ?**

If unique ids will be given typical search method could work like this:

```
    element = browser.find_element_by_id('createProjectArea')
```

Comment: Use xpath and comment on your code. Dont id everything not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

> Should I force developers to give unique ids to core elements

on the last project we did accurately so. Of course there're bunch of elements and it's mess to cover every element, but then you start using css_selectors and xpath, trying not to be related on neighbor elements if it's possible.

And try to use:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'selector')
```

or

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'selector')
```

in the newest selenium version(4) will start getting warnings about their deprecation:

- find_element_by_id
- find_element_by_name
- find_element_by_tag
- find_element_by_xpath
- etc

> warnings.warn("find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use
> find_element() instead")

Answer (score 0):

Assign a known ID to any field or control that you want your Selenium tests to specifically manipulate.  This can make the test more resistant to subsequent changes in the topology of the HTML – unlike other alternatives which depend on the surrounding context.  That can be a real advantage.

I think that it's a balancing act.  If creating IDs helps you write your tests, then it's perfectly fine to do so for that purpose, where and when it actually applies.  But I would not go so far as to *"force* developers to ..."  Don't litter the field with IDs that are not actually going to be referred-to by the application or by the tests.